# JSON URI too Long?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am working with a plugin I found that generates an Org Chart based on data passed to it. The plugin is called [OrgChart](https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart). I have tried to paste a hardcoded JSON object of my data as well as through a `POST` AJAX call to fetch it. Both instances result in a browser error of `414 URI too Long`.

When I check the `console > network` tab, it appears that it is trying to load the JSON data as a `GET` request?

Here is a link to the demo that I am working from. The only difference in our setups is the amount of data bening used in the chart.

http://dabeng.github.io/OrgChart/ajax-datasource/

Is it typical for a plugin to use a `GET` to pull in the `JSON` data? I am just trying to see if there is any way I can tweak this plugin to get it to work as large data sets should be expected for a plugin like this.

**Edit:**
This is how I am running the plugin. I have an AJAX call that fetches the data from the database and then passes that to the plugin. It fetches the data fine in the first `POST` call which is my AJAX statement but then it appears the plugin is trying to receive that data back over a URL.
[image]

```
// On Ready
$(document).ready(function(){

     $.ajax({
        url: "api/fetchOrgChart",
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: {
            QID: 'Q1234'
        },
        error: function(err) {
            alert(err.statusText);
        },
        success: function(data) {

            org = makeTree(data, 'root');

            // Render the org chart
            $('#chart-container').orgchart({
              'data' : JSON.stringify(org),
              'depth': 50,
              'nodeContent': 'title'
            });
        }

    });

});

// Creates our nested hierarchal array based on the manager id and employee id
function makeTree(data, parentId) {
  return data.reduce(function(r, e) {
    if (e.MgrQID == parentId) {
      var children = makeTree(data, e.QID);
      if (children.length) e.children = children
      r.push(e)
    }
    return r;
  }, [])
}
```

Comment: Without seeing your code and a detailed description how to reproduce the problem this is impossible to answer.

Comment: @Tomalak - Added some code as an example.

Comment: It does not look like the POST request you make in your code and the request you see on the console are the same. The entire URL seems to be different.

Comment: Correct, my AJAX call is fetching the data and storing it as the variable `org`. In the plugin within the success statement, I am passing that as the data and it appears the plugin is then requesting that data over a URL which is what I find strange and appears to be the problem. The data you see in the second URL is what was received by my AJAX call and its being encoded and sent to the plugin I assume.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed, the `.orgchart()` call makes a POST request of its own

Comment: Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart/blob/master/dist/js/jquery.orgchart.js), I see that all .ajax calls are hard-coded to be GET requests. This looks like a good reason to open an issue against the repo...

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have submitted an issue and will see if I can stumble my way through the plugin and possibly find and update those calls in the interim.

Comment: Sure you can turn them into POST requests (maybe it's better to fiddle with [jQuery#ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) instead of touching the plugin code) but the question is whether the server end expects/handles those requests.

Comment: I think the problem is this line: `'data' : JSON.stringify(org),` the plugin sees you've passed a string, so it uses that as the URL. Just make it `'data': org` and I'm guessing it'll work.

Comment: @Mike - The reason I added that is because without it, it appears to fail. I removed it and this was the result in the console. GET https://xxxxxxxxx/emp/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I lowered the amount of data that I was fetching from the database and now I get a 400 error due to the URL. It is under the URI limit in so its not throwing the other error. It is just appending the data to the URL of the directory it is in "/wwwroot/emp/{datahere}". Definitely seems to be something with the AJAX / GET calls.